# Android - WebView botão voltar

Tags: android

Tenho um espelhamento de um site no WebView e gostaria que ao pressionar o botão **Voltar** do Smartphone, voltasse para página anterior. Atualmente se eu pressionar o botão **Voltar** do Smartphone, o aplicativo é minimizado (Fica em segundo plano).
Eu não sei fazer isso, alguém pode me ajudar?

**MainActivity**

```js
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1);
        wv.loadUrl("https://www.xxxx.com.br");
        wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        WebSettings ws = wv.getSettings();
        ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        ws.setSupportZoom(false);
```

**Manifest**

```js
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/ic_stat_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />


            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você deve usar a função **onKeyDown**, exemplo:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                if (wv.canGoBack()) {
                    wv.goBack();
                } else {
                    finish();
                }
                return true;
        }

    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Dessa forma, o Java vai entender que é para retornar uma página do webView que está sendo exibido.

Para que funcione, você deve declarar o WebView lá em cima primeiro, exemplo:

```
private WebView wv;
```

E então, dentro do onCreate declara-lo, exemplo:

```
wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1);
```

Assim você terá acesso a variável **wv** dentro do método **onKeyDown**

E caso não existam mais páginas para serem retornadas, irá cair no **else** e ai sim irá fechar a **Activity**

---

**Edit:** Na sua MainActivity, ficaria dessa forma:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView wv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1);
        wv.loadUrl("https://www.xxxx.com.br");
        wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        WebSettings ws = wv.getSettings();
        ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        ws.setSupportZoom(false);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                if (wv.canGoBack()) {
                    wv.goBack();
                } else {
                    finish();
                }
                return true;
        }

    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

}

Comment: Por favor, você pode montar o script com base no meu **MainActivity**, motivo: Apresentou erro (Sou leigo em programação).

Comment: Eu editei a minha resposta com o código de como ficaria na sua MainActivity, da uma olhada, qualquer dúvida avisa

Comment: Após a edição obtive sucesso.